# Filter and calculation of duration

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, formula, array-formulas

I have a sheet with raw data and cannot think of the right formula. Here is how the data look like

[image]

What I want is a formula that would help me calculate the duration between the Com failure and the Com restored for every electrical panel. The issue is that the same panel could have failure and restore on multiple days and I need the formula to find the right restore for the correct failure. Hope that makes sense.

This is what I get after trying MattKing solution and it is partially correct
[image]

Comment: Is it somehow organized?, You should substract the restore time from the previous appearance of failure from that same panel?

Answer (score 0):

in column E, in cell E2, you can put this formula.

If it's a row where it's been restored, that formula should just "look up" the last "com failure" for that panel and subtract that date and time from the date and time in that row.

```
=IF(B2="Com restored",C2+D2-VLOOKUP(A2,SORT(FILTER({A$1:A1,C$1:C1+D$1:D1},B$1:B1="Com failure"),2,0),2,0),)
```

Comment: I tried this formula to get it automized all the way but it doesn't work perfectly: =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="Com restored",C2:C+D2:D-VLOOKUP(A2:A,SORT(FILTER({A2:A,C2:C+D2:D},B2:B=" Com failure"),2,0),2,0),))